# For a function $f:S\to S$, if $f$ is injective, then $f\circ f\circ f$ is injective

Tags: functions

For a function $f:S\rightarrow S$, if $f$
  is injective, then $f\circ f\circ f$
  is injective.

Is my attempt correct? 
True. Let $S=A$
 , $S=B$
  and $S=C$ and $f=g$
. Suppose $f:A\to B$
  and $f:B\to C$
  are both injective. Then $f\circ f$
  is injective. Now suppose $g:A\to C$
  is injective. Then, $f\circ f\circ f$
  is injective. Thus proving the claim

Comment: Generally speaking the xcomposition of injective maps is injective. Just use the definition: if $x\neq x'$, then &c.

Comment: your attempt doesn't make a lot of sense. it will help you to sit down and review definitions.

Comment: @hunter
I edited my attempt. Please check again. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take $x,y$ such that: $$(f\circ f \circ f)(x) = (f\circ f \circ f)(y).$$ Then $\color{blue}{f}$ injective gives: $$\color{blue}{f}(f(f(x))) = \color{blue}{f}(f(f(y)) \implies f(f(x)) = f(f(y)). $$ Repeat until you conclude that $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Start by showing that if $f$ and $g$ are both injective, then $f\circ g$ is injective.  (Once you've proven that, let $g=f\circ f$.)  To show that $f\circ g$ is injective, suppose it is not and ask why?  If it is not, then there are two values $x_1\neq x_2$ so that $f(g(x_1))=f(g(x_2))$.  Is $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$? Why?  Let $x_3=g(x_1)$ and $x_4=g(x_2)$.  If $x_3\neq x_4$ then can $f(x_3)=f(x_4)$?