# Suppose $f:S \rightarrow S$ for some set $S$. Prove that, if $f \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

This is my first attempt at a proof so I feel it's probably wrong. A problem similar to this one

[For a function $f:S\to S$, if $f$ is injective, then $f\circ f\circ f$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300229/for-a-function-fs-to-s-if-f-is-injective-then-f-circ-f-circ-f-is-inject)

Suggested using proof by contrapositive but something feels off about it. The book (Rudins Analysis) cryptically suggests 'Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$ and apply $f$ to both sides.' as the solution to this problem but I'm still not sure how that becomes a formal proof so here's my attempt.

Suppose $a \in S$ and $b \in S$. By definition $f(f(a))=f(f(b))$ implies that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Using proof by contrapositive, if $f$ is not injective there exists a value $a'$ that is not $a$ such that

$\exists a' \ni f(a)=f(a') \text{ and } a \neq a'$

but applying the function $f$ to both sides implies

$\exists f(a') \ni f(f(a))=f(f(a')) \text{ and } f(a) \neq f(a')$

This contradicts the assumption that $f \circ f$ is injective thus proving by contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote that “By definition $f(f(a))=f(f(b))$ implies that $f(a)=f(b)$.” By definition of what?

Then you wrote that “there exists a value $a′$ that is not $a$”. What is $a$?

You can prove it following Rudin's suggestions: is $f$ is not injective, then there are $a,b\in S$ such that $a\neq b$ and that $f(a)=f(b)$. But then $f\bigl(f(a)\bigr)=f\bigl(f(b)\bigr)$, which is impossible, since we are assuming that $f\circ f$ is injective.

Comment: 'You wrote that “By definition f(f(a))=f(f(b)) implies that f(a)=f(b).” By definition of what?'

What I should've written is by definition of an injective function

'But then f(f(a))=f(f(b)), which is impossible, since we are assuming that f∘f is injective.'

Isn't this not a contradiction technically? So long as $f(a)=f(b)$ then this doesn't contradict an injective function because. So long we assume $f(f(a))=f(f(b))$  this doesn't contradict $f \circ f$ being injective? All $f \circ f$ being injective implies is that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, not that $a \neq b$

Comment: Please see the edit i made. I'm (probably incorrectly) assuming that, as long as $f(a)=f(b)$, nothing about $f \circ f$ being injective implies a contradiction so long as $f(a)=f(b)$ (it's not a contradiction so long as the functions of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ produce the same value.)

Comment: The question was not edited and anyway I have answered the original question. I will not keep adapting my answer to new versions of the question.